# How to list all zip files in a specified directory?

Tags: ant, fileset

I am trying to retrieve the list of all zip files present in a directory.

I have a directory `${src}` which contains some zip files and I am using the following code

```
<target name="test">  
<dirset id="dist.contents" dir="${src}" includes="*.zip"/>  
<property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dist.contents"/>  
<echo message="${prop.dist.contents}" />  
</target>
```

but it only echoes null.

I also tried `includes="*"` but it didn't make any difference.

I am using Ant version 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html):

> A DirSet is a group of directories.

So since you want zip *files*, you should use a FileSet.